# Arduino Sensor reading not uploading on mySql using phpmyadmin and xampp

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, arduino, xampp

I want to upload my sensor reading on mysql database using phpmyadmin and xampp. I am using arduino uno connected to my esp8266 for wifi connection. Following is my code uploaded in the arduino. And this is my serial monitor output: [serial monitor output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9taVs.png) . But i am unable to upload any of the reading in the database. Can you please help what i am doing wrong? I am new to all this stuff so dont know much in depth.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <WiFiEsp.h>
#include <SPI.h>

char ssid[] = "ZONG MBB-E8372-B67D";           // your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = "08522547";
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
SoftwareSerial ser(2, 3); //Rx, Tx
#define trigPin A0
#define echoPin A1

void setup() {
pinMode (trigPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode (echoPin, INPUT);

 delay(2000);
 Serial.begin(115200);
 Serial.println("Wifi Started");
 ser.begin(115200);
 WiFi.init(&ser);

 // check for the presence of the shield
 if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
Serial.println("WiFi shield not present");
 // don't continue
 while (true);
   }

   while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
   Serial.print("Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: ");
   Serial.println(ssid);
     // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network
   status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    }
     Serial.println("You're connected to the network");
  }

void loop() {
int duration, distance, distance1, distance2, duration1,  duration2, distance5, distance4;
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(1000);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
 distance = (duration / 2) / 29.1;
 Serial.print(distance);
 Serial.println("cm");
 delay(700);
  double value = distance;

  String cmd = "AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"";
 cmd += "127.0.0.1"; //ip address of phpmyadmin
  cmd += "\",80\r\n";

 ser.println(cmd);
  delay(5000);

 if (ser.find("Error")) {
ser.println("AT+CIPSTART error");
return;
 }
 String cmd2 = "GET /write_data7.php?"; // Link ke skrip PHP
 cmd2 += value;

   cmd2 += " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
  cmd2 += "Host: 127.0.0.1\r\n\r\n\r\n"; // ip address of phpmyadmin
    String pjg = "AT+CIPSEND=";

   pjg += cmd2.length();
    pjg += "\r\n";
  ser.println(pjg);
  ser.println(cmd);

   delay(500);



     if (ser.find(">")) {
      ser.print(cmd2);
       }
     else {
    ser.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
    // alert user
      ser.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");

       }
      }
```

and this is my php code:

```
$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

 $sql = "INSERT INTO connected_car_1.sensor (value) VALUES ('".$_GET["value"]."')";    

   // Execute SQL statement

  mysql_query($sql,$con);



mysql_close($con);
?>
```

the url i am using is "http://localhost/write_data7.php?"
and the error i get is *Notice: Undefined index: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\write_data7.php on line 11*
and if instead of localhost i use my ipaddress i got blank screen.

If i send the url :localhost/write_data7.php?value=100
 i get the value 100.

please help where i am going wrong in tyoing the url or in the ip adress or in the code?

Comment: the url in your code is missing the `value=` part. you are calling write_data.php?100 and this results in an undefined index. So modify it to call write_data.php?value=100 and everything will work like expected.

Comment: I have added that value part in the code. And the url see in my post i am already giving that and i have mentioned that it works too in that way but i dont want to add the value 100 , i want to add the arduino sensor reading. I am just sending the value 100 to check if there is any error in my php file or the database  i have made

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the `value=` part in your url

```
 String cmd2 = "GET /write_data7.php?";
 cmd2 += "value="+value
```

try it like this and the you will call the correct url.

Comment: I have tried this too already..but still i am unable to send. Can you tell that how do i have to call the url of write_data7.php file. 127.0.0.1( phpmyadmin ip address) . should the url be like 127.0.0.1/write_data7.php?

Comment: i have checked by giving the url as mentioned in my comment. The entries are incremented in the database but blank and i get the same error:
Notice: Undefined index: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\write_data7.php on line 11